# Edge Crease and multiple subsurf modifiers

Tags: modifiers, edges, subdivision-surface

If you crease an edge, then subsurf modifier won't round it. But if you have 2 subsurf modifiers, the second will ignore the crease and round the edge. Is there a way around this? I have a situation where I want one subsurf, then some other modifiers, then a second subsurf. Using Simple instead of Catmull-Clark doesn't help.

[image]

Top: The starting cube with all edges creased and 1 subsurf modifier with 2 levels of subdivison.
Bottom: The same starting cube with all edges creased and 2 subsurf modifiers with 1 level of subdivision each.

Comment: can you please add an image demonstrating your issue?

Comment: mmmh strange because in my case a second subsurf increase the sharpness (seems normal as it virtually adds edge loops)

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this problem. You could use a manual edge loop to sharpen edges if needed, though thats tedious. Why do you need two subsurfs?

Comment: @Ignatiamus I am using Cloth Sim and I want to be able to control the amount of subdivisions before the cloth modifier as I will need different qualities depending on the shot. And then I need a subsurf after the cloth modifier to help smooth things out and bring the model to the final render quality.